# media query min bound isn't working

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I have this query in my css. Originally the `width` is `100%` and when the screen size is between `768` and `1024` px I want it to be `50%`. The `max-width` seems to be working because the `width` gets halved but once the screen width goes below `768` it still stays 50%. Should it not revert back to `100%`?

```
@media (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px)
  .item {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: (min-width: 767px) will do that

Comment: seems to work fine for me https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgrJJm

Comment: What browser are you testing this in?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a couple curley brackets. It should look like...

```
@media (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .item {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```